# Assigning group id to sequences of numbers in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to group measurements by sequences, filling the runNumber column as shown below. Every time the timestep restarts, a new runNumber has to be assigned to that sequence.
Example data:

```
    timestep robotid  runNumber 
1        0       1        1
2        0       2        1
3        1       1        1
4        2       2        1
5        0       1        2
6        1       1        2
7        1       2        2
```

This first attempt works on small datasets, but takes very long on the actual data.

```
mydata$runNumber <- 1
runcounter <- 1 

for(counter in 2:nrow(mydata)){
  if(mydata[counter-1, c("timestep")] > mydata[counter, c("timestep")]){
    runcounter <- runcounter + 1
  }
  mydata[counter, c("runNumber")] <- runcounter
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = '    timestep robotid  runNumber 
1        0       1        1
                  2        1       1        1
                  3        2       2        1
                  4        0       1        2
                  5        1       1        2', header = TRUE)

df1$runNumber <- NULL  # remove runNumber column
```

**Code:**

If the timestep restart is indicated by the value `0`, then we can check for it, and then take the cumulative sum of the logical vector from it.

```
within(df1, runNumber <- cumsum(timestep == 0))
#   timestep robotid runNumber
# 1        0       1          1
# 2        1       1          1
# 3        2       2          1
# 4        0       1          2
# 5        1       1          2
```

using data.table will be even faster. Try this:

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df1)[, runNumber := cumsum(timestep == 0)]
df1
```

**EDIT: based on new data posted in the question**

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text='timestep robotid  runNumber 
                  1        0       1        1
                  2        0       2        1
                  3        1       1        1
                  4        2       2        1
                  5        0       1        2
                  6        1       1        2
                  7        1       2        2')
df1$runNumber <- NULL
```

**Code:**

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df1)[, runNumber := {
  x <- rle(timestep == 0)  # find run length for values = 0
  y <- cumsum(x$lengths)[!x$values]   # extract the indices
  rep(seq_len(length(y)), c( y[1], diff(y)))  # create group ids
} ]

df1
#    timestep robotid runNumber
# 1:        0       1         1
# 2:        0       2         1
# 3:        1       1         1
# 4:        2       2         1
# 5:        0       1         2
# 6:        1       1         2
# 7:        1       2         2
```

Comment: This already works a lot faster then my solution, the problem however is that a timestep can have multiple robotid's. So a timestep restart is indicated by a 0 with a higher value in the previous row. My apologies for the ambiguous example. `timestep robotid  runNumber 
           1        0       1        1
           2        0       2        1
           3        1       1        1
           4        1       1        1
           5        2       2        1
           6        0       1        2
           7        1       1        2`

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much for this elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `tidyr` package has a handy `fill` function.  Assuming each restart the timestep ==0.

```
df<-read.table(header=TRUE, text="timestep robotid 
0       1
1       1
2       2
0       1
1       1")

#find the number of starts
nstarts<-length(df$timestep[df$timestep==0])
#set each restart to the sequence
df$runNumber[df$timestep==0]<-1:nstarts

#fill the rows
library(tidyr)
fill(df, runNumber)
```